# Display entire line from InputStream

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I am having problem reading something from a COM Port, I am using txrx library in a JavaFX application. Here's the code that displays what it's reading:

```
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
        String bytesin = null;
        String fullLine = " ";


        if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
        {
            try
            {
                byte singleData = (byte)input.read();

                if (singleData != CR_ASCII)
                {
                    bytesin = new String(new byte[] {singleData});
                    fullLine = fullLine+bytesin;
                    System.out.println(fullLine);
                }
                else if ( singleData == CR_ASCII)
                {
                    System.out.println("CR detected!");
                }
                else
                {
                    statusLabel.setText("Read!");
                }
                }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                statusLabel.setText("Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");
                System.out.println("Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")");

            }
        }


}
```

== The problem with that code is that it displays everything in a single character per line.
My USB device is outputting the following text (the Chars are ASCII, not characters):

```
**T-Pod-1Ch**(Char 13)(Char 10)
```

however my code output gives this:

```
 *
 *
 T
 -
 P
 o
 d
 -
 1
 C
 h
 *
 *
CR detected!


 *
 *
 T
 -
 P
 o
 d
 -
 1
 C
 h
 *
 *
CR detected!
```

Comment: Why would it do anything else? You set `fullLine` to a whitespace character and then just read a single character from the stream, and then do a `System.out.println(fullLine)`. If you want to read a whole line of text, why not create a `BufferedReader` and call `readLine()` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to read a line of text from a stream is to use the `readLine()` method in `BufferedReader`. Is there any reason you can't do:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

// ...

String fullLine = reader.readLine();
System.out.println(fullLine);
```

instead of trying to read a single byte at a time (and essentially re-inventing the wheel).

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know about that. I was working off some other examples I've read online.

Answer (score 0):

`(byte)input.read()` reads a single byte and `System.out.println(fullLine)` prints this character and a new line after that. So the code works. Try to use `System.out.print(fullLine)` instead.